# How to get an html link in java for sending an email

Tags: java, html, email

I need to send an email through java application and the email contains a link.
The value of the link comes dynamically.
I tried the followin:

```
messageBodyPart.setText(messageBody,"UTF-8","html"); 

StringBuffermessageBody = "Go to <a href = '" +CommonConstant.APP_URL + "' > </a>"

public static final String APP_URL = "http:\Application\Check";
```

But this doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Please take your time to ask a well thought out question, with relevant source code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to compose html body. see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) for detail

Comment: Actly what i was referring to was this:

message.setContent("<a href = 'http:link'> </a>,
                            "text/html" );
                            
This will work.

Now if i define a String strLink = "http:link";  and then modify the above piece of code 
message.setContent("<a href = '" +strLink +'> </a>,
                            "text/html" );
This doesn't work.